# Using git to control semantic versioning

Tags: git, version-control, versioning

In git I would like to "mark" certain commits. For instance I would like to "mark" commits which break the software's REST API, so that I can remember to bump the major version no. (I use [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)).

Ideally I should be able issue a git command to see if any commits since last release/tag contain a "mark", because then I know that the next version no. should bump the major no.

The "mark" is not a tag (in git terms), since tags are unique. I anticipate, that there could be several identical "marks" since last release, to signal that the API is broken.

The current workaround is to write "MAJOR:" or "MINOR:" in commit messages.

Are there any suggestions on how I can use git for this?

Comment: But the main function of tag in git is mark the main versions (release point). And an annotated tag is nearly the same as a commit.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that tag names must be unique—but there are an infinite number<sup>1</sup> of unique tag names *beginning with* `mark/`, such as `mark/1`, `mark/2`, and so on.  Or, you can use reference names that are not in `refs/tags/`; or you could use Git's "notes", although it's easier to detect whether a tag or other reference is an ancestor of one commit and a descendant of another:

```
highmark=$(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/marks | wc -l)
nextmark=$((highmark + 1)
git update-ref refs/marks/m$nextmark HEAD
```

(this assumes you never delete, with `git update-ref -d`, any of these marks—if you do the "high mark" computation must find the highest existing number instead of simply counting).  To test if mark $N is "between" tag T1 and HEAD:

```
if git merge-base --is-ancestor T1 refs/marks/m$N &&
   git merge-base --is-ancestor refs/marks/m$N HEAD; then
       ... mark N is at or beyond tag T1 and at or before HEAD ...
else
       ... mark N is not between those two points (inclusive) ...
fi
```

Alternatively, you might store, in or outside the repository, and if inside the repository, in a plain blob—a blob is Git's internal format for raw file data—a file that simply contains the hash IDs of all "marked" commits.  The file itself can be stored in a tagged or otherwise-referenced commit that may, but need not be, on any branch; or you can tag the blob itself.  For instance:

```
git show marks > /tmp/all-marks      # extract existing marks
git rev-parse HEAD >> /tmp/all-marks # add a new mark
git tag -f marks $(git hash-object -w --stdin < /tmp/all-marks)
```

If you store the blob under a commit, you can keep a history of marks by making new commits for each new updated "marked IDs" file.  This is in some ways similar to the way `git notes` work, but instead of writing files whose names are the IDs of commits, you are simply writing a file named "marks" (stored via a tree that is then pointed-to by the commit, that the mark reference—whether it's a tag like `refs/tags/marks`, as in the tag example above, or a reference like `refs/marks`, like the `m` series references above but only using one reference).  Since each commit has a parent pointer, you can save the previous commit, which saves the previous tree, which saves the previous blob/marks-file, and you can even run `git log` on these commits, to see who updated the marks, when, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, finite, but limited only by disk space and name patterns.  The pattern proposed here, counting decimally within file names in a single name-space, can only count to 10<sup>254</sup> on typical Unix-ish file systems, with their 255 byte component-name-length limit.  Practically speaking, you'd probably not want to go much past a thousand or so before making the names hierarchical, e.g., `refs/marks/123/456/789` once you are into a few million marked commits.

OSes also impose maximum path lengths, but you would run out of commit IDs long before you hit those: 2<sup>160</sup> is only 1 461 501 637 330 902 918 203 684 832 716 283 019 655 932 542 976, or about 1.462 sexdecillion in the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_large_numbers) nomenclature.  Worse, your chance of a hash collision gets too high after a few quintillion objects anyway, so we need only count to perhaps 10<sup>18</sup>.